Hello, I am Ugandan Citizen, currently residing in Netherlands on an Orientation Resident permit), how do I apply for a Germany student Visa?
I got an admission to study in Germany, how do I generally go about the student Visa application, Should I apply from Uganda, Netherlands or Germany?

You should be able to apply from the German consulate in Amsterdam. In practice, applying from Uganda would probably also be possible but it shouldn't be necessary. Going to Germany and applying for a residence permit directly is usually not permitted (but there are exceptions).
In general, you can always apply from your place of residence and your Dutch permit should be enough to establish that you presently reside in the Netherlands. Some countries will also examine applications from visitors, especially if you can argue that returning to your country of residence would represent undue hardship but in your situation you don't need to rely on that.
